# java jdbc how can I properly add data into JsonObject

Tags: java, jdbc, json

I am retrieving 2 records from the MySQL database using JDBC and turning them into a JsonObject however the code is not working correctly for example: I am getting this result

```
{"locations":[{"city":"OrlandoOrlando","state":"WVFL"}]}
```

instead of

```
{"locations":[{"city":"Orlando","state":"WV"},{"city":"Orlando","state":"WV"}]}
```

I know how I am getting but can seem to find out how to correct it, this is my code

```
String city="";
String state="";
try {
   JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
   Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
   ResultSet rs;
  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select city,state from zips limit 2");
   rs = ps.executeQuery();
   while (rs.next()) {
// The problem is in this area the: city+ and state+
       city+= rs.getString("city");
       state+= rs.getString("state");
   }
   jo.put("city",city);
   jo.put("state", state);
   JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
   ja.put(jo);
   JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
   mainObj.put("locations", ja);
```

The problem is in the city+ and state+ Strings above, however if I do this

```
while (rs.next()) {
   city= rs.getString("city");
   state= rs.getString("state");
 }
```

It fixes everything but only gets back 1 record instead of 2 which then looks like this

```
{"locations":[{"city":"Orlando","state":"WV"}]}
```

Any suggestions would be great..

Comment: How about creating the JSONArray before your loop and adding the extracted values inside the loop?? JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();while (rs.next()) {
   city= rs.getString("city");
   state= rs.getString("state");jo.put("city",city);
   jo.put("state", state);ja.put(jo);
 }

Comment: Hey I just tried that but it only gives me {"locations":[{"city":"Orlando","state":"WV"}]} as a result.

Comment: Do you have an entry with FL in your DB? Can you check with 3 records of different states?

Comment: Yes I have an entry with FL,WV under the state column in my records and yes I can. I am trying out new ways of appending the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes in such a way to build the JSONArray from SQL output.

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select city,state from zips limit 2");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
while (rs.next()) {
    jo.put("city", rs.getString("city"));
    jo.put("state", rs.getString("state"));
    ja.put(jo);
}

JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
mainObj.put("locations", ja);
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread for much cleaner implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160351/create-json-object-by-java-from-data-of-mysql

Comment: Downvoting. If we have multiple rows returned in `rs`, will this solution not cause `ja` to have only one`jo` values?

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONObject jo = null;
Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select city,state from zips limit 2");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
while (rs.next()) {
    jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("city", rs.getString("city"));
    jo.put("state", rs.getString("state"));
    ja.put(jo);
}
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
mainObj.put("locations", ja);
```

Comment: Thanks for the revision, this gets all new records too.

Comment: This just copies previous answer and tweaks a bit. Editing existing is better approach.